# Image Not Uploading in custom field in product add/edit(admin side)

Tags: magento2, adminform, image-upload, magento2.4

I have created a custom phtml file and added in product page add/edit time by the help of below link https://aureatelabs.com/magento-2/how-to-call-custom-phtml-in-admin-product-ui-component-form-in-magento-2/ . I have also added file field but I am not able to upload image in this field.

[image]

When I uploading image then it's showing the selected images count but when I click on the product save button then in the observer(Where I getting all custom value) it's showing only name in post but in image file($_FILES) it's showing blank. Other data able to get in post method

Below are my phtml file code

```
<?php
$productId=$block->getProductId();
$adminUser=$block->getAdminUserList();

$salesPerson=$block->getSalesPerson();
$i=1;
$repairtype=[
    'consult' => 'Needs Consultation',
    'service' => 'Needs Service',
    'parts' => 'Needs Parts',
    'house' => 'Needs In House Repair',
    'paint' => 'Needs Paint',
];
?>

<div>
    <?php

    $aname = '<option></option>';
    foreach ($adminUser as $person) {
        $aname .= "<option value='" . $person['user_id'] . "'>" . $person['username'] . "</option>";
    }

    foreach($repairtype as $key=>$rtype){
    ?>
    <div id="<?php echo $key;?>_div">
        <div class="box-border <?php echo $key;?>_box">
            <div><?php echo $rtype;?> <input onclick="showhiderepair('<?php echo $key;?>',<?php echo $i;?>)" class="repair_checkbox" name="repair[<?php echo $key;?>][<?php echo $i;?>][need]" id="<?php echo $key;?>_checkbox_row_<?php echo $i;?>"  type="checkbox"/></div>
            <div style="display:none" id="<?php echo $key;?>_data_<?php echo $i;?>">
                <div class="admin__field" >
                    <textarea class="admin__control-text " type="text" id="<?php echo $key;?>_note_<?php echo $i;?>" name="repair[<?php echo $key;?>][<?php echo $i;?>][note]"  data-form-part="product_form"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="admin__field" >
                    <label class="admin__field-label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __("Repaired By :")?></span></label>
                        <div>
                            <select name="repair[<?php echo $key;?>][<?php echo $i;?>][repaired]"  id="<?php echo $key;?>_repaired_<?php echo $i;?>"  class="select select-status-days required-option-select admin__control-select" title="" data-form-part="product_form"><?php echo $aname;?></select>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <button class="mycontact-popup" id="pur"><?php echo __("Contact Info")?></button>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="admin__field" >
                    <label class="admin__field-label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __("Start Date : ")?></span></label>
                    <div>
                        <input class="admin__control-text  datepicker" type="text" id="<?php echo $key;?>_startdate_<?php echo $i;?>" name="repair[<?php echo $key;?>][<?php echo $i;?>][startdate]"  data-form-part="product_form" value=""/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="admin__field" >
                    <label class="admin__field-label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __("Estimated Date On ".ucfirst($key)." Arrival :")?></span></label>
                    <div>
                        <input class="admin__control-text datepicker" type="text" id="<?php echo $key;?>_date_<?php echo $i;?>"  name="repair[<?php echo $key;?>][<?php echo $i;?>][date]" data-form-part="product_form" value=""/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="admin__field" >
                    <label class="admin__field-label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __("Need Callback : ")?></span></label>
                    <div>
                        <input class="repair_admin_checkbox" name="repair[<?php echo $key;?>][<?php echo $i;?>][callback]" id="<?php echo $key;?>_callback_<?php echo $i;?>"  type="checkbox"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="admin__field" >
                    <label class="admin__field-label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __("Callback Date :")?></span></label>
                    <div>
                        <input class="admin__control-text datepicker" type="text" id="<?php echo $key;?>_callbackdate_<?php echo $i;?>" name="repair[<?php echo $key;?>][<?php echo $i;?>][callback_date]" data-form-part="product_form" value=""/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="admin__field" >
                    <label class="admin__field-label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __("Hours Worked :")?></span></label>
                    <div>
                        <input class="admin__control-text " type="text" id="<?php echo $key;?>_hoursworked_<?php echo $i;?>" name="repair[<?php echo $key;?>][<?php echo $i;?>][hoursworked]" data-form-part="product_form" value=""/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="admin__field" >
                    <label class="admin__field-label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __("Upload File :")?></span></label>
                    <div>
                        <input class="admin__control-text" type="file" id="<?php echo $key;?>_files_<?php echo $i;?>" name="repair[<?php echo $key;?>][<?php echo $i;?>][repair_files][]" multiple="multiple" accept="image/jpeg,application/pdf" data-form-part="product_form" value=""/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="addmore_repair" id="<?php echo $key;?>" ><?php echo __("Add More")?></button>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

I am not able to add form value like **enctype= multipart/form-data**

Please let me know how can we upload image and get by $_FILES

Comment: Other data are save or not ? Have you get data image array ?

Comment: Other data able to get in post method, for Image I tried with the request,$_FILES and $_POST(Only name coming)

Comment: add data-form-part attribute to input type and value is your ui form name like this <input class="admin__control-text" type="file" id="<?php echo $key;?>_files_<?php echo $i;?>" name="repair[<?php echo $key;?>][<?php echo $i;?>][repair_files][]" multiple="multiple" accept="image/jpeg,application/pdf" data-form-part="product_form" value="" data-form-part="Your_ui_form_name" /> check and update me.

Comment: but data-form-part already added 'product_form'